# Redirect request to folder with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

How can I set *.htaccess* to make

**http://www.example.com/folder**

go to (assuming this is not made automatically)

**http://www.example.com/folder/**    ?

Comment: Does `/folder/` exist, or is this a virtual directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For existing directories, Apache already provides a configuration option via mod_dir. Add the `DirectorySlash` directive to your main configuration file, or otherwise the root .htaccess file.

```
DirectorySlash on
```

See [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash).

Comment: What if I want `/folder` to go to `/folder/subfolder/` ? (assuming both directories exists)

Comment: That's an internal rewrite (or an external redirect if you want to show that in the address bar). See [the info page for mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info).

Comment: I agree with Sumurai8 solution , for DirectorySlash on, so to reply your comment answer i suggest you read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652794/use-htaccess-to-fix-misspelled-urls